# Android app link - disambiguation dialog issue when Associating a website with multiple apps

Tags: android, applinks

When associating a website with multiple apps in IOS, the order of app in json decides what app opens after scanning the QR Code of the linked url. The first app in the json will automatically open without a disambiguation dialog of choosing between the multiple apps in the json.

Different apps handle exactly the same path link for the SAME resource under the same web host.
For example, Apps are all linked to https://example.com, without any additional path

However, on Android, the order of app in well-known json can not decide what app opens when associating a website with multiple apps. The first app in the json will not automatically open. Instead, there is a disambiguation dialog of choosing between the multiple apps(the browser app is not included) in the json. 
If the json file only includes one app, the app will automatically open without a disambiguation dialog between the app and browser.
And the android version is 8.0.0, API 26, SamSung SM-N950U1

So I am curious that why on android, the first app in the well-known json can not open directly???
Or on Android, it is just designed to show a disambiguation dialog of choosing between the multiple apps in the json?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to have several apps being opened by the same path? Universal Links and App Links are designed to create that contract of 1-1 between the click domain and the App. What's the use case that you are trying to solve?

Comment: For example my several apps include yahoo mail, yahoo sports, yahoo finance and so on. I have no idea which app users have downloaded in their phones. However click domain is unique for design. After clicking the click domain, I wanna open the app directly which is downloaded in users' android phone according to their order in .well-known json without displaying a disambiguation dialog of choosing all downloaded apps in the .well-known json file.